# ag-grid :- enableMultiRowDragging is not working in ag-grid 24

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I am a new learner of angular. I am working on ag-grid. I have to upgrade the ag-grid from the version ag-grid 21 to ag-grid 24.

I am trying to add enableMultiRowDragging but is not working. Please have a look at the code.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
              [ngClass]="[sorted ? 'ew-blue-compact ew-blue-dashboard' : 'ew-blue-compact ew-blue-dashboard draggableItem']" 
              id="myGrid" 
              #agGrid
              style="width: 100%;" 
              [style.height.px]="getGridHeight()" 
              [gridOptions]="gridOptions" 
              [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId" 
              (paginationChanged)="handlePaginationChanged($event)" 
              (sortChanged)="HandleSortChanged($event)"
              [rowSelection] ="'multiple'" 
              [rowDragManaged]="true"
              [enableMultiRowDragging] ="true" 
              [immutableData]="true" 
              [animateRows]="true"
              (rowDragEnter)="onRowDragEnter($event)"
              (window:resize)="onWindowResize()" 
              (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
              (rowDragMove)="onRowDragMove($event)"> 
          </ag-grid-angular>
```

in this code, `[rowDragManaged]="true"` is missing. When I am adding it to ag-grid-angular then the grip icon will not show.

I tried many efforts but it is not working.

I tried to make a simple project than [rowDragManaged]="true" and [enableMultiRowDragging] ="true" is working. But it is not working on upgrading the ag-grid from version ag-grid 21 to ag-grid 24.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ag-grid does not support pagination. Please make the pagination false in ag-grid.